# Show :$(\forall x A) \to A ${$x/t$} wouldnt be a Tautology if we didnt rename bounded variables in substitution.

Tags: logic

Show  :$(\forall x A) \to A ${$x/t$} wouldnt be a Tautology if we didnt rename bounded variables in substitution.

I have been trying countless Formulas for A but all of them end up Tautologies. Can i get some hint on what to try ?

Comment: You have to consider the proviso on the axiom: "provided that where $t$ is *substitutable* for $x$ in $A$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $\forall x \exists t ~ t > x$